# How to use a lambda to loop without saving values

Tags: python, lambda, iteration

In Django I have a page where users can be added or removed from a group. I am retrieving formdata for a list of users, and then determining which ones need to be removed or added from the group. For some reason using the lambda inside map didn't affect any change, but as I understand, it should, right?

I wanted to do something like:

```
map(lambda x: x.group.remove(this_group).save(), users_to_remove)
map(lambda x: x.group.add(this_group).save(), users_to_add)
```

but it wouldn't work. I had to use loops:

```
for user in users_to_remove:
    user.coi.remove(this_coi)
for user in users_to_add:
    user.coi.add(this_coi)
```

Comment: You're misusing the map function...

Comment: First of all, your loop body and your lambdas do something different (waht's the `save` supposed to do?). Second, your question lacks a minimal example with concrete data structures that showcases the problem. On top of that, you don't use `map` in order to avoid loops, you use `map` when you want to build a new iterable. If you don't want to get shot in code review, that is.

Comment: As Tim suggested, your example is not detailed enough for us to reproduce the issue. See the following example: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3a5812c6326e52671580d8f30df172f6

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code is supposed to do, because you did not provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I am hesitant to even answer this "question". However, it looks like you want to use `map` in order to modify an iterable in place and discard the return value of `map`.

You can do that, but it's a bad idea. Here's basically what you are trying to do (or what I have deduced from your code):

```
>>> kill = 1
>>> mylist = [[1, 2], [3, 1, 9]]
>>> map(lambda x: x.remove(kill), mylist)
[None, None]
>>> mylist
[[2], [3, 9]]
```

As you can see, `kill` was removed from every sublist, but you built a completely unnecessary, (temporarily) memory consuming list `[None, None]` (the return value of the `lambda` function for each sub-list in `mylist`).

You should use `map` when you want to apply a function to an iterable and actually care about the return value of that function, i.e. you want a new iterable of all the returnvalues. Using `map` to mutate an iterable in place is against its intended use (and therefore confusing to most python programmers) and inefficient.

If you need a loop, use a loop. There are no extra points for writing fewer lines.

<sub>Except when you get upvotes for a clever oneliner on SO.</sub>